# Can I use a MAX7219/7221 chip to drive 16 common anode RGB LEDs?

Tags: led, led-driver, max7219

I am using a MAX7219 to attempt to power 16 common anode RGB LEDs. The MAX 7219 has a resistor which must be wired in series with its ISET pin in order to set the current per segment of the IC, as per [the datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max7219-max7221.pdf).

[image]

Now, the issue comes with the fact that green and blue LEDs have a voltage drop of ~3 V, whereas red ones are usually in the 1.9 V range. That said, if I use a 10.6 kΩ resistor in order to get 40 mA current with 3 V LEDs, what will happen to the red LED with its lower forward voltage?

As far as I understand, setting the segment current means the whole line (row or column) gets that 40 mA, but the brightness of the LEDs is irrespective of how many on a single line are turned on. How does the MAX7219 "know" how many LEDs are on at the same time?

EDIT: Adding a photo of my circuit. The green modules' top 6 pins can be ignored, they are part of a different sub-module. The bottom 4 pins represent the common anode and the three cathodic colors.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MAX7219 is designed to drive common cathode LED displays. However, any multiplexed LED display matrix will have common cathode and common anode connections. As long as there is only one LED at each intersection, it will work. And each LED will have a constant current.

Here is how it is intended to be used. I have represented the transistors as switches. The top portion is a simplification. The LED display is the common cathode type.

There are separate current drivers for each segment output, all programmed via the same external resistor. The voltage drops of the LEDs don't need to be matched, that is the reason for having constant current drivers. The current source is crude, but good enough. There are curves in the spec that show how the current will change vs output voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYrbLW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Drawn as a matrix with Common Cathode LEDs. The software will work nicely.

[image]

Common Anode LEDs. The software will be ugly if you are driving 7-segment displays.

[image]

Your proposed circuit. This should work. The software may be a little weird, but worst case, use a lookup table.

[image]

Comment: I have updated my question with my schematic.